# What is the first date of documented usage and attribution of the term "white race" and/or "white races"?

Tags: etymology

From my own independent research into the origin of the terms, *"white"* and *"race"*, and specifically the terms *"white race"* or *"white races"* as applied to natural persons, the earliest primary source that I have been able to locate so far is in *An Essay on the Inequality of the Human Races* by Arthur de Gobineau (1853-1855)

> The white races are, further, distinguished by an extraordinary
>   attachment to life. They know better how to use it, and so, as it
>   would seem, set a greater price on it; both in their own persons and
>   those of others, they are more sparing of life. When they are cruel,
>   they are conscious of their cruelty; it is very doubtful whether such
>   a consciousness exists in the negro. At the same time, they have
>   discovered reasons why they should surrender this busy life of theirs,
>   that is so precious to them. The principal motive is honour, which
>   under various names has played an enormous part in the ideas of the
>   race from the beginning. I need hardly add that the word honour,
>   together with all the civilizing influences connoted by it, is unknown
>   to both the yellow and the black man… It would not have been all gain.
>   The superiority of the white race would have been clearly shown, but
>   it would have been bought at the price of certain advantages which
>   have followed the mixture of blood.

Citing primary sources, what is the first documented date and attribution for the term *"white race"* and/or *"white races"* as applied to one or more natural person?

Comment: There are attestations from the 1770s.

Comment: @TRomano Not sure what you mean by "attestations"? The first usage of "White-woman" in British/American colonial jurisprudence is in Marlyand colony in 1681, where the prior Act of 1664 was repealed wherein the terms "White-women" and "whitewoman" et al. were substituted for "English or freeborn women" et al. That is not "white race" or "white races". Would prefer to avoid discussions about the topic in comments. Kindly post an answer to the question, including citation to primary sources.

Comment: Do you want the phrase "white race" or anything to do with the color "white" in a racial context?  Not sure why you're bringing in the phrase "white-woman".

Comment: As for **attestation**, see #2: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attestation

Comment: @TRomano Usage of the terms "white men" and/or "White-women" predate usage of the terms "white races" and/or "white race". "race" and "white" have nothing to do with a color. "racial context" did not exist until the term "race" was invented and used relevant to classification of humans. Thus the question asks when the terms "white" and "races" or "race" were first combined.

Comment: I still don't know why you are telling me this. I said nothing about "white woman".

Comment: "*White*, the natural colour of man, all other tints proceed from greater or lesser heat of climates; ... among **white races** of people, our own country bids fairest for pre-eminence" [emphasis mine] *An history of the earth, and animated nature,* Volume 8, by Oliver Goldsmith. Dublin, 1776.

Comment: @TRomano Prior to the usage of "White-women" in the Maryland statute, those women were referred to as "English freeborn women". The term "White" was _gradually_ incorporated into laws, until reaching the refinement state, where the invention of the concept of _plural_ "white races" predates the eventual _singular _"white race", making the political class monolithic. In any event, kindly post an answer to the question.

Comment: Why are you telling me about it having been discredited?? I am citing a text where the phrase you asked about is used.

Comment: "Although it be a little heterodox, he is persuaded the black and white Race have originally sprung from different-coloured first Parents."  in *A New General Collection of Voyages and Travels consisting of the most Esteemed Relations, which have been hitherto published in any Language, etc etc*. London, 1745.

Comment: @TRomano Ok. Why are you posting an answer in comments? Post the formal answer to the question.

Comment: No, I will not post as an answer, as I do not know if these are the earliest attestations to be found. They're just what I've been able to find in the first few moments.

Comment: @TRomano That is what mean. Perform your due diligence and _then_ post an answer to the question. Comments are not for answers.  Mod squad could scrub the above comments at any time. The question is immediately clear. There is no need for discussion whatsoever.

Comment: "Mod squad", a blast from the past.

Comment: @JEL Specifically the terms stated at the question. The definition of "European" is "muddy". Europe is defined by some as a continent though is a not a distinct landmass re Asia. The Mercator map "projects" Europe in the center of the planet and grossly exaggerates the actual square mileage of the geography. In addition, the original, "indigenous" people in Europe also had "dark" skin; "dark-skinned" people have an ancient historical presence in Europe proper by any geographical misinformation or true dimensions; the Irish are considered European though for a substantial period not "white" etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The earliest use of 'white race(s)' I found, after only the 1655 poetic mention of a metaphorical contest ("race") as "[chastities white race](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A37212.0001.001/1:8?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=occur;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=white%20race#hl1)", was this from [*The Present State of the Republick of Letters*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=nyp.33433087361568;view=1up;seq=73), v. 14 (Jul.-Dec. 1734), p. 65:

> In Reply to this Pretence, Father *Malsert* tells us it is well known that the Children of *Noah* were white: that the Descendents of *Japhet* inhabited the Islands in the *Mediterranean*, the Northern Part of *Asia*, and all *Europe*: that the Posterity of *Sem* possess'd great Part of *Asia*, as far as the River *Cophen* in *India*; and that the Race of *Cham* settled in *Palestine*, *Egypt*, and the Coast of *Africa*, now call'd *Barbary*, and formerly *Lymbia*, *Numida*, and *Mauritania*; all of which people are of the white Race.

Comment: The 1734 citation appears to be exactly on point. I note that it appears in the July issue of _The Present State of the Republick of Letters_ as part of a discussion of the (presumably contemporaneously written) book, _An Enquiry into the Origin of the Negros and the Americans_, by a French author, "Father Augustus Malsert, of the Order of Charity." I get the impression that persons seeking early expressions of white supremacist thought dressed in biblical and natural-law theory might find this book of interest. It is unclear, however, whether Malsert's book was ever translated into English.

Comment: The lineage descends through the next two appearances of the phrase, in the 1735 [*A voyage to Guinea, Brasil, and the West-Indies*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.31175035187577;view=1up;seq=57), "'tho it be a little Heterodox, I am persuaded the black and white Race have, *ab origine*, sprung from different colored first Parents", and next in the 1765 [*The administration of the colonies*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=aeu.ark:/13960/t9s18sm49;view=1up;seq=191), "three sons to Noah. These three species, or race, are--The white race--the red--the black."

Comment: @SvenYargs, I didn't find Malsert's work in English or French, even in WorldCat.

Comment: I found what may be Malsert's piece, under the title "[Dissertation sur l'Origine des Negres](https://books.google.com/books?id=HB0FAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA150&lpg=PA150&dq=%22Dissertation+sur+l%27origine+des+Negres%22&source=bl&ots=a9UyQEo_39&sig=ACfU3U0LebFp9OOyhJCxI2nWwC38KkIXZQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7y4uYmszgAhWxJDQIHTPnBPUQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22vivans%22&f=false)" (no date). It is just 24 pages long, which would help explain why it doesn't show up in WorldCat. The typography fits a 1733 publication date, and the text has much to say on the supposed origins of "les Noirs" and "les Blancs."

Comment: On pages 19–20, the author launches into a discourse on the posterity of "Noé" and "Cham," which again suggests a match, but there is also a reference to "une Dissertation sur ce sujet luë à l'Academie en 1740," so something is clearly amiss here, chronologically speaking.

Comment: @SvenYargs It's [Article 88 in *Memoires pour L'Histoire des Sciences et des Beaux Arts*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=ucm.5325091019;view=1up;seq=53). See page 1941, "de la race des Blancs" and surrounding.

Comment: @JEL For accuracy and to avoid confusion, the earliest date of the of a primary source where the term "white race" was used that you have been able to locate  is 1734, correct?

Comment: @guest271314, In the sense of interest, and in English, yes.

Comment: @JEL What do you mean by "In the senses of interest"? The subject matter? Is  that a qualifying clause? Are there French or German usage of the term that predate 1734?

Comment: @guest271314, the meaning you stipulated (I think). As I mentioned in a comment on the question, *OED* (for example), splits hairs about the meaning of 'race' (noun) in senses approximating the sense you may have intended in your question. Boiled down, those senses are more or less specific to family lineage, ranging to "genetic". The idea that some 'races' (ironic quotes) are descended from Noah is distinct from the later idea that 'race' is genetic.

Comment: @guest271314, I don't speak French or German, and so can't speak to the question about earlier uses of 'white race' in those languages...beyond the 1733 use in French mentioned and quoted in my comment in reply to Sven.

Comment: @JEL What lead you to draw the conclusion that the idea of "race" relevant to descent from the mythology of "Noah" and the mythology of "genetic" is distinct? How and why are are you weighting mythologies differently? Or, is your point that English literature and academia makes an arbitrary distinction between those two mythological ideas? You have answered the actual question. Just attempting to communicate and understand as clearly as possible what your answer conveys.

Comment: @guest271314, the senses given in *OED*, under the umbrella "A group of people, animals, or plants, connected by common descent or origin" but ranging from "A group of people belonging to the same family and descended from a common ancestor; a house, family, kindred." to "According to various more or less formal attempted systems of classification: any of the (putative) major groupings of mankind, usually defined in terms of distinct physical features or shared ethnicity, and sometimes (more controversially) considered to encompass common biological or genetic characteristics."

Comment: @JEL From rabbit-hole to rabbit-proof fence, if an individual relies on those  equivocations: maximization of confusion.